# Xamarin Studio could not reference .dll file

Tags: c#, xamarin-studio, gtk#, dll-reference

I'm trying to use gpgme-sharp in Xamarin Studio with GTK#(.NET). Everything is ok, but i get the following error:

> Unable to load DLL 'libgpgme-11.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

If I add it as reference(my application target x86 platform and that dll is also x86), I get the following error:

> File 'Path\To\File\libgpgme-11.dll' is not a valid .Net Assembly

Can I get some help please? Where should i put this file?

Comment: What kind of app are you trying to make ? Which platform ?

Comment: I'm trying to use gpgme-sharp, to generate keys, to encrypt and decrypt. I need them for my desktop app(Windows and Mac OS).

Comment: Well, read the [Read me](https://github.com/slayercat/gpgme-sharp/blob/master/README) in GitHub. It says it'll work on Windows and Linux ( Mac not mentioned) in addition to that *You need at least GnuPG and GPGME.* As what was tested is Windows Vista. So no guarantee it'll work under newer versions of Windows

Comment: Right now I use it on Windows. I already have installed GnuPG and GPGME. I need to add that libgpgme-11.dll to may project, but i can't do it because I don't know what reason..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my own question, to close this topic. The file was corrupted... All good now!